# Which graphical card should I buy to be compatible with Ubuntu 16?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, amd-graphics

```
man radeon
```

outputs that my graphical card "Radeon HD 7700 series" is compatible with Ubuntu 16, but it doesn't.

I googled for Nvidia, and they also have problems with Ubuntu 16. That's why I'm a little confused here

Requirements:

- display ports: 2 Mini-DisplayPort
- Resolution: minimum 2560x1600
- PCIe16, PCIe4 or PCIe1

Comment: Hardware is off topic on askubuntu ;)

Comment: Yeah, but still is a critical part of this Ubuntu version. I think this question is going to have a lot of views on askubuntu

Comment: "lots of views" is not a target for AU. Questions and answers that are re-usable by others and hardware has a very limited timeframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am currently using 7790 and i am ok with it. I would change with nvidia cause of the proprietary drivers. AMD's open source drivers are not so reliable yet. So my suggestion is 7790/GTX750

Comment: I ordered GeForce GTX 960 Gaming 4GB. I will keep this thread up to date with results

Comment: Use proprietary drivers. Let me know how it works out

Comment: Well, it does not work on Linux. Now I have this one  NVIDIA NVS 310; that works well on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: its not possible. This card is tested many times...are you sure you did it right?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you buy a computer and install an OS on it you can always have problems. You need to buy a preinstalled computer.

I don't get why you are buying a specialized HW to install an alien OS on it.

What I do is buy a computer with a very simple video card, nowadays they perform really well. Nothing specialized like CUDA or OpenCL just plain video card with OpenGL. This should be of common knowledge in the Linux community ...

We should be here to install Linux and kick **s of non-standard HW and that should be all the talk about Ubuntu and HW

*It's like a generation of Kamikazes is in rampage*

I learned this the hard way in 2008 and not making that mistake again. Games that rely on specialized HW are not worth the trouble believe me. Hyper-Realism is not that enjoyable. ( sorry to be off-topic )

Not so Happy Llamas and they're lookin' at yo...